# How to sort rows by value in certain column

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet of data that I would like to organize. There are multiple rows with values sorted by column. I would like to sort rows `3-19` based on the value in column `B`.

The algorithm I am using is this:

```
=SORT(3:19, B3:B19, FALSE)
```

And my error is:

```
Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in B2.
```

I have looked at [this Google Support page](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150) but cannot get it to work properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to sort the rows in place, with the output of `sort` overwriting the original rows. Spreadsheet formulas can't do that.

Instead, put the `sort` on another sheet. For example, if the original unsorted data is in Sheet1, the formula will be

```
=SORT(Sheet1!3:19, Sheet1!B3:B19, FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks! This also works if you make room for the sorted data on the same sheet.